# Redirect api/ request to api.php and all other request to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Am building an api for an existing application which redirects all request to index.php. But now i want to direct all request with api to api.php e.g Redirect http://domain.com/api/user/create to api.php and other requests without api e.g www.domain.com/users/all to index.php
Here is my htaccess

```html
Options -Indexes

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/font-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #Fix Rewrite
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    #Live version goes here
    #RewriteBase /

    #Dev config goes here
    RewriteBase /myapp



    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*,:*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^var.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    ## always send 404 on missing files in these folders
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|theme|js|screens)/

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
  

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```